# Error: value r is not a member of String for a simple regex

Tags: scala

For the following straightforward regex that works fine in the `repl` :

```
val tsecs = """[^\d]+([\d]+)*""".r
tsecs: scala.util.matching.Regex = [^\d]+([\d]+)*
```

Why would it not compile - either in Intellij or on the commandline via `mvn compile` ?

```
val tsecs = """[^\d]+([\d]+)*""".r

error: value r is not a member of String
[ERROR]         val tsecs = """[^\d]+([\d]+)*""".r
```

The version is scala 2.10.5 in all cases.

Comment: I guess the second regexp is not valid and cannot compile: `*` make no sense for me in `([\d]+)*`

Comment: @cchantep  They are identical regex's (take a look again) - and the error is not a regex compilation problem but that `r` is not recognized: so there is not even any attempt to do the parsing anyways.

Comment: The error sounds as if it doesn't have `@inline implicit def augmentString(x: String): StringOps = new StringOps(x)` in scope.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few ways to disable Predef.

```
import scala.Predef.{wrapString => _, augmentString => _,  _}

object Test extends App {
  def r = "x".r
}
```

Or

```
object Test extends App {
  val wrapString, augmentString = 42
  def r = "x".r
}
```

Or compile with `-Yno-imports`.